# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xef38 in tid 17996 (pool-10-thread-)

Tags: android, kotlin, threadpool, rx-android, android-mvp

I'm facing **NDK** error. that is

> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xef38 in tid 17996 (pool-10-thread-)

What i'm doing is below:

**First step:**
in **view activity**: i'm calling function from presenter and send latitude, longitude to find the address through reverse geocoding
in **presenter class**: Below is the function

```
private  fun getAddressObservable(latitude: Double, longitude: Double): Observable<List<Address>> {

        val geoCodeObservable: Observable<List<Address>> = locationProvider.getReverseGeocodeObservable(latitude, longitude, 1)

        return geoCodeObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    }


private fun getAddressObserver(): DisposableObserver<List<Address>> {
        return object : DisposableObserver<List<Address>>() {
            override fun onComplete() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Completed")
            }

            override fun onNext(t: List<Address>) {
                val address = t[0].getAddressLine(0)
                if (isSource) {
                    mainView.sourceAddress(address, latLng)
                } else {
                    mainView.destinationAddress(address, latLng)
                }
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.message)
                if (isSource) {
                    mainView.sourceAddress(App.context.resources.getString(R.string.na), latLng)
                } else {
                    mainView.destinationAddress(App.context.resources.getString(R.string.na), latLng)
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**Now second step:**
When the i got the response from above API in `sourceAddress and destionationAddress` **view functions**.. Then i call another **RESTAPI**

```
override fun sourceAddress(address: String?,latLng: LatLng) {
        sourceAddress= address.toString()
        tvAddSource.text=address
        tvAddSource.setTextColor(Utils.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
        sourceLatLng=latLng
        **mainActivityPresentator.getNearbyDriver(latLng.latitude,latLng.longitude,sourceAddress.toString())**
    }
```

**Now the in presenter call:**

```
override fun getNearbyDriver(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, address: String) {
        getObservable(latitude,longitude,address).subscribeWith(getObserver())

    }

    private fun getObservable(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, address: String): Observable<NearbyDriversResponse> {
        return ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface::class.java).getNearbyDriversRequest(preferenceAdapter.getUserModel()?.id, preferenceAdapter.getUserToken(), latitude, longitude, address)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    }

    private fun getObserver(): DisposableObserver<NearbyDriversResponse> {
        return object : DisposableObserver<NearbyDriversResponse>() {
            override fun onComplete() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Completed")
            }

            override fun onNext(@NonNull response: NearbyDriversResponse) {
                response.status?.let {
                    when {
                        Objects.equals(it, ResponseMessages.RESPONSE_STATUS_SUCCESS) -> {
                            mainView.responseNearByDriver(response)
                        }
                        Objects.equals(it, ResponseMessages.RESPONSE_STATUS_FAILURE) -> {
                            response.message?.let {
                                mainView.failureMessage(it)
                            }

                        }
                        Objects.equals(it, ResponseMessages.RESPONSE_STATUS_ERROR) -> {
                            mainView.errorMessage(App.context.getString(R.string.invalid_token))
                        }
                        else -> {
                            mainView.errorMessage(App.context.getString(R.string.default_error_message))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onError(@NonNull e: Throwable) {
                e.message?.let {
                    Log.d(TAG,it)
                }
                mainView.apiFailure(App.context.getString(R.string.internet_connection_failure))
            }

        }
    }
```

If i stop calling **getNearByDrivers**

```
mainActivityPresentator.getNearbyDriver(latLng.latitude,latLng.longitude,sourceAddress.toString())
```

then App is working fine
if i start calling this line .. then after few mins .. App throws below error

> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xef38 in tid 17996 (pool-10-thread-)

I'm fedup. trying to resolve from 3 days. still didn't resolve

**NOTE: `getAddress` API is called in `mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener()`**

**Issue resolved in API>= nougat by `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`. Didn't work for lollipop devices**

Comment: It's caused by a NPE, check this: [Diagnosing Native Crashes](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/native-crash).

Comment: How NPE?
I've gone through each part of code. even logcat the API. everything that i can do. i did .. still not resolved

Comment: @LuisMuñoz will you help me to resolve the issue? i'm in critical stage of my projecct

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not an android guy, just gave the error a try in case it was kernel related.

Comment: No problem. i googled almost everything but couldn't find what to do!

Comment: do you have native code?

Comment: @user1506104 above is native code but in kotlin. do you mean java?

Comment: hello, if this issue is not resolved, could you please add full log stackstrace? are your using third party library as objectbox...

Comment: @AnisBENNSIR still not resolved ! this is the only error i got into Logcat. no other errors are showing!

Comment: other log may be useful, just filter your application log. Are you seeing in log ( Log.d(TAG, "Completed")) on your observer ?

Comment: @AnisBENNSIR after 1 or 2 successful calls then app stuck and crash.. . one more thing i tried in emulator and it works fine.. but when i run on my lollipop version mob it crashed!